# Owncloud/Apache Server won't increase max file upload

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have tried just about everything I can think of on this one.
I am currently trying to increase the max file upload size on our apache owncloud server.

I have changed the `/etc/php.ini` values for:
`upload_max_filesize` and
`post_max_size`

After restarting the httpd service, the file size has not yet changed.
I tried several different values without success.
I then edited the `.htaccess` in the root of the owncloud directory for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, restarted, and still am not able to surpass the `2m` limit.

I created a phpinfo file, and it does in fact say that it is pulling from the `/etc/php.ini` file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What size limit you are looking for ?

Also, which php.ini file you are changing .. means location ?

Comment: I'm trying for 200mb.  I tried that as 200m 200MB 200 MB and 200 m.  None of those seem to work.
I've been editing the /etc/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

OP back.  I figured out the issue.  I ran `php -c /etc/php/php.ini -i | grep upload_max_filesize` and discovered a small typo elsewhere in the php.ini file.  (I attempted to edit the timeout value, and had left in a parenthesis).  After taking out the parenthesis, and restarting the service, the upload value was correctly adjusted.

Comment: Congrats! Please mark your solution as the accepted answer so others may benefit. (-:

Answer (score 0):

Create a sample.php file with phpinfo() function in your owncloud document root to check which php.ini is being used, its location and parameters values.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
>
```

Then change the following parameters in php.ini and restart the web server and relogin to owncloud before try uploading again.

```
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

Make sure you are using latest version of owncloud.

Comment: Somesh, Here's what I get for loaded configuration file:
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini 
Running PHP version 5.3.3 

It does not seem that editing post_max_size, and upload_max_filesize to those values and restarting the service worked.

I am currently running owncloud version 4.5.4 which it says is up to date

Comment: run the following cmd to check all php.ini file and their upload values:  **updatedb && grep upload_max_filesize `locate php.ini`**  "locate php.ini" value is in backtick .. I don't know how to place that in comment. \`

Comment: So I did do that, and it found 2 files (in usr/share/doc) set as 2M.  I set them both as 200M, and restarted the service.  After refreshing the phpinfo page it still seems like for some reason it is stuck on 2M.

Comment: Can you share value of "Loaded Configuration File" from your phpinfo output? If you change value in php.ini, restart web service, refresh phpinfo page then it should reflect in phpinfo unless you are making changes in diff php.ini.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini
Then for the output of your command I get:
/etc/php.ini:upload_max_filesize = 200 and /usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/php.ini-development:upload_maxfilesize = 200 and /usr/share/doc/php-common-5.3.3/php.ini-production:upload_maxfilesize = 200

Comment: Hi Mike, I can see that your value is just 200, not 200M. Can you please do the same and try restarting it.

If it still doesn't work, then can you please send me the output of this command `cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini |egrep 'upload_max_filesize|post_max_size'`

Comment: Once you restart the web server, always remember to reload the Web page in the browser, as it needs a reload to reflect the changes. 

Also, I hope you are not using some sort of caching mechanism, like xcache or eaccelerator or Varnish.

Comment: It says cat: /usr/local/lib/php.ini: No such file or directory.  After restarting, it unfortunately came up with the same error.  All of them however are now set to 200M

Comment: So, is the upload working now ? .. if not then can you please give me the output of this command  `cat /etc/php.ini |egrep 'upload_max_filesize|post_max_size`

Comment: Following two settings working for me and I am using the same version of owncloud. `post_max_size = 200M   upload_max_filesize = 200M`.

Comment: The output of the command is: upload_max_filesize = 200M.  It however is still not letting me upload anything greater than 2mb. I'm not sure if there is a rule of linking to an image, but I took some screenshots, just in case there is something simple I'm just overlooking. http://i.imgur.com/t8zdD.png

Comment: I have the same problem. My phpinfo() reveals 900M and a php.ini at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. The output of php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  -i | grep upload_max_filesize is 900M. The output of php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  -i | grep post_max_size is 1000M. I keep getting an error that the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive specified in the HTML was too large or something to that effect.